# "XML not defined" RSS translator

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been googling for an hour now but couldn't find an answer to this. When I run this script https://script.google.com/home/projects/1B3Sw2dCh4-45YrPEgAR1oPoU3OlThTSiQ5pyTJOhyeBVuYZCaYj3VuuH/edit (i changed the RSS URL, and translation from "en" to "cs") But when i run it, there is this error "XML not defined" would you be so kind and help me?

Comment: You should share the content of the linked script within the question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Xml` with `XmlService` on line 60.

More details here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service

Comment: Thank you for your answer though when i changed it it says this: Exception: The parameters (String,(class)) don't match the method signature for XmlService.parse.
parseRSS @ Kód.gs:60
doGet @ Kód.gs:40

Comment: As specified in the documentation, the XmlService.parse() function only receives one parameter of type String, not two parameters as you are doing. Line 60 should be like this: var doc = XmlService.parse(txt);